# How to overload the subscript operator with swig Python

Tags: c++, python, swig, operator-keyword, subscript

I have a class which contains a `std::vector<Foo>` where `Foo` is a class containing a key, value, comment, etc. Please note that there is a reason why I am using a vector and not a dictionary.

I have overloaded the subscript operator in C++ such that `foos["Key Name"]` will search through the vector for a Foo object with key matching "Key Name" (where `foos` is a `std::vector<Foo>`).

I use [SWIG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWIG) to create a Python wrapper for my library, and I would really like for this subscript operator to extend into Python. In other words, I want to be able to use the `foos["Key Name"]` for finding objects in the vector in Python.

Any tips on how to make SWIG recognize the subscript operator and overload it in Python? I am a little surprised that I couldn't find examples of people doing this online. I guess most people just use a `std::map` and have SWIG convert it to a Python `dict`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In straight Python, if you want to overload the subscript operator, you would create a `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` class method. As a simple example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.storage = {}

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.storage[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.storage[key] = value
```

So if you want to have C++ handle this, my very best guess (no, I haven't verified this) is that you would create a `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in C++. You can either do this directly in your C++ code, or use the `%extend` directive within SWIG to call off to your C++ `[]` operator.

Answer (score 2):

Python indexers are `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods.

See [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.1/HTML/Python.html) on how to implement them.

Or you may use `%extend` [clause](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html#Python_nn43) in more modern SWIG.